# Table with 2 FK that points to the same table

Tags: mysql, database

I use MySQL with MyISAM engine. Lets say I have the following 2 database tables:

TableX

```
ID, Person1ID, Person2ID
```

Person

```
ID, Name
```

How should my query look like since I have 2 foreign keys that points to the same table?
I've been trying to join tables but out of luck...

I want to select

```
ID, Name, Name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to join `Person` table twice in your case, here is an example:

```
SELECT j.ID, 
       p.Name AS `Person 1 Name`,
       p2.Name AS `Person 2 Name`
  FROM TableX j
  JOIN Person p
    ON p.ID = j.Person1ID
  JOIN Person p2
    ON p2.ID = j.Person2ID
```

Comment: +1. This is a good example of a query that returns the specified result. (It might be good to note that if a matching row is not found in the Person table, the row from TableX would not be returned; implementing an "outer" join would allow the row from TableX to be returned, along with a NULL value for Name when a matching row is not found.)

Comment: Slight better worded would be `it will return all rows that are present in the table Person for both id's referenced, if any is missing it will not yield any results for that specific row.`

Comment: Thank you guys. My mistake was that I didnt use Alias... feel stupid now... Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of a query that performs JOIN operations to retrieve the related rows from the Person table:

```
SELECT t.ID
     , t.Person1ID
     , t.Person2ID
     , p1.ID          AS `p1_ID`
     , p1.Name        AS `p1_Name`
     , p2.ID          AS `p2_ID`
     , p2.Name        AS `p2_Name`
 FROM TableX t
 LEFT
 JOIN Person p1 
   ON p1.ID = t.Person1ID
 LEFT
 JOIN Person p2
   ON p2.ID = t.Person2ID
ORDER BY t.ID
```

If you want to exclude rows where there is no matching row in the Person table, you can remove the `LEFT` keyword to replace the "outer" join operation with an "inner" join.